# MutableLiveData not updated until I navigate back and forth

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I'm currently writing an Android ecommerce app. In the cart(locally stored using room) when I first add a product the quantity is shown as null and the total price is not updated. But when I go back to the home page and back again to the cart fragment, the correct values are shown. Any idea why this is happening?

Below is the relevant code.

Thank you.

DaoViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.shoppingapp.ui

import androidx.lifecycle.*
import com.example.shoppingapp.data.local.Cart
import com.example.shoppingapp.data.repository.CartRepository
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject


@HiltViewModel
class DaoViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: CartRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val cart: LiveData<List<Cart>> = repository.cartItems.asLiveData()
    private val _itemQuantity = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val itemQuantity: MutableLiveData<Int> = _itemQuantity
    private val _itemPrice = MutableLiveData<Double>()
    val itemPrice: MutableLiveData<Double> = _itemPrice
    private val _totalPrice = MutableLiveData<Double>()
    val totalPrice: MutableLiveData<Double> = _totalPrice


    fun addProductToCart(cart: Cart) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.insertProduct(cart)
        }

    }

    fun removeProductFromCart(cart: Cart) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.removeProduct(cart)
        }

    }

    fun updateQuantity(value: Int, id: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.updateQuantity(value, id)
        }

    }


    fun getQuantity(id: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _itemQuantity.setValue(repository.getQuantity(id))
        }

    }

    fun calculatePrice(id: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.calculatePrice(id)
        }
    }

    fun getTotalPrice() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _totalPrice.value = repository.getTotalPrice()
        }
    }

    fun subtractQuantity(id: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.subtractQuantity(id)
        }
    }

    fun addQuantity(id: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.addQuantity(id)
        }
    }
}


class DaoViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: CartRepository
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(DaoViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return DaoViewModel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")

    }


}
```

CartAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.shoppingapp.ui

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions
import com.example.shoppingapp.data.local.Cart
import com.example.shoppingapp.databinding.CartLayoutBinding
import java.text.NumberFormat

class CartAdapter constructor(
    private val listener: onItemClickListener,
    private val daoViewModel: DaoViewModel
) :
    ListAdapter<Cart, CartAdapter.CartViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CartViewHolder {
        val binding = CartLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return CartViewHolder(binding)

    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CartViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)



        if (currentItem != null) {
            holder.bind(currentItem)
        }


    }


    inner class CartViewHolder(val binding: CartLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(cart: Cart) {
            binding.apply {
                Glide.with(itemView)
                    .load(cart.image)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                    .into(itemImage)
                daoViewModel.getQuantity(cart.id)
                daoViewModel.calculatePrice(cart.id)
                itemTitle.text = cart.title
                val price: Double = cart.price
                val formattedPrice: String = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(price)
                itemPrice.text = "Price: ${formattedPrice}"
                itemQuantity.text = cart.quantity.toString()
                removeItem.setOnClickListener {
                    listener.onItemClick(cart)
                }
                addButton.setOnClickListener {
                    listener.onQuantityAdd(cart.id)
                }
                decreaseButton.setOnClickListener {
                    listener.onQuantitySubtract(cart.id)
                }
            }

        }


    }

    interface onItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(cart: Cart)
        fun onQuantityAdd(id: Int)
        fun onQuantitySubtract(id: Int)
    }


    companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Cart>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(
            oldItem: Cart,
            newItem: Cart
        ): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItem: Cart,
            newItem: Cart
        ): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }


}
```

CartFragment.kt

```
package com.example.shoppingapp.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.shoppingapp.R
import com.example.shoppingapp.data.local.Cart
import com.example.shoppingapp.databinding.FragmentCartBinding
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import java.text.NumberFormat

@AndroidEntryPoint
class CartFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_cart), CartAdapter.onItemClickListener {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<StoreViewModel>()
    private val daoViewModel by viewModels<DaoViewModel>()
    private var _binding: FragmentCartBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false)
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        _binding = FragmentCartBinding.bind(view)
        val adapter = CartAdapter(this, daoViewModel)
        daoViewModel.itemQuantity.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {}
        daoViewModel.getTotalPrice()

        daoViewModel.cart.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        }

        binding.apply {
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            //Disable animations
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }
        val price: Double = daoViewModel.totalPrice.value ?: 0.0
        val formattedPrice: String = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(price)
        binding.totalPrice.text = "Total Price: ${formattedPrice}"
        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            val action = CartFragmentDirections.actionCartFragmentToCheckoutFragment()
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }


        binding.recyclerView.isVisible = true
        binding.button.isVisible = true
        binding.emptyText.isVisible = false
        binding.totalPrice.isVisible = true



    }

    override fun onItemClick(cart: Cart) {
        daoViewModel.removeProductFromCart(cart)
    }

    override fun onQuantityAdd(id: Int) {
        daoViewModel.addQuantity(id)
    }

    override fun onQuantitySubtract(id: Int) {
        daoViewModel.subtractQuantity(id)
    }


}
```

Comment: This `daoViewModel.itemQuantity.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {}` observer do nothing shouldn't it update the quantity?

Comment: The quantity is updated in the ProductsAdapter class. I put this because the livedata needs to be observed

Comment: You're only updating the price once, in ``onViewCreated``, right? That's using the current values stored in the view model, and when you first start, it doesn't have an initial value - so you're defaulting to ``0.0``. You're calling ``getTotalPrice`` before that, but that's running in a coroutine (and talking to the Room DB) so that will finish later, long after you've called ``totalPrice.value``. You shouldn't really be using ``value`` - set observers on the ``LiveData`` objects you care about, and update the UI when they change (e.g. put your ``totalPrice`` calculation stuff in an observer)

Comment: Can you give me an example on how that works please?